# A simple many to many SQL example

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I'm trying to figure out a good way of doing an SQL query that returns a table of user names and their choices (there are a set number of choices and a user can have many choices) as in the example below. I haven't been able to find a good simple example of this (other than how the relationship is laid out). Is this solution viable or is there a better way of doing it? I seem to get the table I'm looking for.

```
SELECT
users.name,
choices.choice as choice
FROM 
choice
JOIN relation ON choice.choice_id = relation.choice_id
JOIN users ON users.name_id = relation.user_id;
```

Gives me the correct table:

```
+------+--------+
| name | choice |
+------+--------+
| amy  | a      |
| amy  | b      |
| amy  | c      |
| joe  | d      |
+------+--------+
```

The simple database looks like this:

Users

```
+------+---------+
| name | name_id |
+------+---------+
| amy  |       1 |
| joe  |       2 |
+------+---------+
```

Choices

```
+----------+---------+
| choice_id|  choice |
+----------+---------+
|        1 | a       |
|        2 | b       |
|        3 | c       |
|        4 | d       |
+----------+---------+
```

Relation

```
+----------+---------+
| choice_id| user_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        3 |       1 |
|        4 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: For a many-to-many relationship this is the correct structure, but surely any given tweet will only have one user (making it a one-to-many relationship)?

Comment: that is true @MarkBannister. i used a bad example. I felt like I was hitting my head against a brick wall and wanted to know if this is the correct way of doing it. thanks